# liferay 6.0.6 how to use DynamicQuery for class com.liferay.portal.model.User

Tags: liferay-6, dynamicquery

I'm deploying a portlet on liferay portal 6.0.6. I used DynamicQuery to access to com.liferay.portal.model.User object.

My code:

```
DynamicQuery userQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(User.class, PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());  
userQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.ilike("screenName","%"+query+"%"));
    try {
        users = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(userQuery);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it throwed:

```
    09:47:02,332 ERROR [DynamicQueryFactoryImpl:83] Unable find model com.liferay.portal.model.impl.UserImpl  
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.model.impl.UserImpl
```

Please point me on how to resolve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Use PortalClassLoaderUtil instead of PortletClassLoaderUtil because User class belongs to liferay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PortalClassLoaderUtil instead of PortletClassLoaderUtil because User class belongs to liferay OOTB.